# Pipe delimited csv file gets an weird look when there are commas within the text to be written

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to create a pipe delimited (|) csv file instead of a comma delimited (,) one. When I write to the file, I can see that the output becomes weird when there are commas within the text. To be clearer, the data should be in column A like the following example. However, the data spread across different columns when there are commas within the text. How can I fix it.

This is ideally what I'm after:

```
Column A
Name|Address
roberts, jim|Flat 10, 36 Sloane Court West, London, SW3 4TB
```

This is what I get instead:

[image]

I've tried with:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(['Name','Address'])
    writer.writerow(['roberts, jim','Flat 10, 36 Sloane Court West, London, SW3 4TB'])
```

> How can I produce a pipe delimited csv file in the right way?

Comment: You have to tell `excel` what the separator is (there's an option in the open dialog I think).

Comment: Btw, tab separated values (TSV) is another option often used by databases.

Comment: When there are commas within a text, you can try using `.replace(",",";")` which will replace commas with semicolon and as a result it will let you have the format you are after.